# Facebook Page Publish link to page tab (iframe)

Tags: facebook, tabs, wordpress, facebook-iframe

I have a wordpress site which is meant to use via Facebook page tab. I have made a page tab and added an iframe tag which opens the site into the page tab. I have added a Facebook plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) to publish new posts to my page's wall to get more traffic to the site. All this works perfectly.

My problem is the following:

The plugin publishes a link to e.g. www.mysite.com/fb/new-event/. The site is meant to use only via the page tab, not at that domain. The link should be customized to open the page in the Facebook page tab via iframe.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this or how to achieve the solution another way?

I think that it can be done by customizing the link to point first at the right Facebook page tab and then inside the iframe to the correct page.

Comment: I don’t really get your problem. If you have an app installed as a page tab on a FB page, you can easily link to it – copy the address from your browser’s address bar when visiting the page tab. What else do you need?